# How to get active buttons ref attribute and assign it to a variable in vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, reference, ref

I have a page with 4 buttons:

```
<button ref='butOne' @click="saveRef">One</button>
<button ref='butTwo' @click="saveRef">Two</button>
<button ref='butThree' @click="saveRef">Three</button>
<button ref='butFour' @click="saveRef">Four</button>
```

I want the `saveRef()` function to save the reference of the button pressed to a variable like `reference`. How would the function look like?

```
data: function(){
    return {
        reference:""
    }
},

methods:{
    saveRef(){
        // what should go here?
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: Yes I marked it as correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the name of referenced button as a parameter of `saveRef` method as follows :

```
<button ref='butOne' @click="saveRef('butOne')">One</button>
```

in the method code :

```
methods:{
    saveRef(btn){
         this.reference=this.$refs[btn] // reference the button element which name passed as parameter
    }
}
```